# Android: MP3 not stopping when the activity ends

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a group a mp3 into an array and my app plays them properly. However when the user quits that activity the activity stops but the mp3s keep being played.

Here is the code:
Initially I play the mp3 files in an array:

```
 MediaPlayer mPlay = MediaPlayer.create(this, Audios[posicion]);
         mPlay.start();
```

When the user clicks on a certain button the activity ends but the MediaPlayer doesnt stop:

```
    bFinalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPlay.stop();
                posicion=0;
                Listening2.this.finish();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this snippet

> try {
>
> mPlayer.stop();
>
> mPlayer.release();
>
> } catch(Exception ex) {
>
> ```
>  ex.printStackTrace()
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Hi , I solved this problem time ago and with mPlayer.release() is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `mPlay.stop()` in `onFinish()` or `onDestroy()` of your activity.

Comment: He is doing that. :) Are you running the media player on a Service?